# Html.Raw not decoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just a query, I have used `@Html.Raw(Item.sometext)` before and it decodes the html tags correctly, I'm getting some data from remore source which is in json format, but when displayed on the page I found Html.raw did not decodes html tags.

To fix the problem I used:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Item.sometext))
```

So my question is, can anyone please tell me why that could be the case, as I'm curious as to the reason. Im using mvc4 and asp.net 4.5

Thanks

George

Comment: I guess because the JSON format is encoded to ensure that escape characters are not causing any problems. So it needs to be decoded back to proper valid JSON before you output it using `Raw`. It would be useful for you to show us what `Item.someText` looks like in the JSON instance.

Comment: Hi musefan thanks, but I thought html.raw decodes html tags etc, so I'm a bit confused as to why I have to decode and decode again

Comment: Hi musefan snippet <p><b>Location. <\/b> <br \/>Mercure Newcastle George Washington Hotel Golf and Spa is a business-friendly hotel located in Washington, close to Washington Old Hall, Angel of the North, and << That is how I get it but when displayed on page html tags where getting encoded, so thats why I used html.raw which did not work, so had to use other method

Comment: So your sample has `\/` which looks like an escape character. Calling the `HtmlDecode` will like result in `<br />` (with the `\` removed) which can then be successfully used by `Html.Raw`. `Html.Raw` does **NOT** decode anything, it just outputs the string exactly as supplied (i.e. as Raw HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer in an attempt to explain better what I mean (in the comments).

Your JSON is formatted for example (which you have supplied) like so:

```
<p><b>Location. <\/b> <br \/>...
```

However, this is not valid HTML. Notice the escape characters used for the slashes '/'. So if you pass this value to `Html.Raw` it will (should) output it, but it's not valid HTML so will unlikely display correctly (if it display anything at all).

This escape character issue can be fixed using `Html.Decode` which will effectively return the following:

```
<p><b>Location. </b> <br />...
```

This is valid HTML, and can therefore be passed to `Html.Raw` without any problems

---

NOTE: `Html.Raw` does not do any encoding/decoding, in fact it explicitly instructs that the supplied value should not be encoded as it is already raw HTML. This is [confirmed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.99%29.aspx):

> Use the Raw method when the specified text represents an actual HTML
>   fragment that should not be encoded and that you want to render as
>   markup to the HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks musefan, I understand a lot better now